# Uncaught ReferenceError when trying to update data in amCharts 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net, charts

I'm trying to write some Javascript to update a simple bar chart using amCharts - it is my understanding that this can be done by simply reassigning the `.data` property of the chart, but when I try to do so I get the following:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: chart is not defined
    at updateChart (Test_charts.aspx:123)
```

Below is a code snippet containing the function that I use to initialize the chart (which seems to work fine) and the function that is throwing me this error.

```
<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
am4core.ready(function() {

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 2025
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395
}];

// Create axes

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "country";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("dy", function(dy, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.index & 2 == 2) {
    return dy + 25;
  }
  return dy;
});

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "visits";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "country";
series.name = "Visits";
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{categoryX}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
columnTemplate.strokeWidth = 2;
columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 1;

}, false); // end am4core.ready()

function updateChart() {
    chart.data = [{
  "country": "Mongolia",
  "visits": 400
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 600
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 100
}, {
  "country": "Eswatini",
  "visits": 1000
}, {
  "country": "Ivory Coast",
  "visits": 1122
}, {
  "country": "Palau",
  "visits": 1114
}, {
  "country": "Nauru",
  "visits": 984
}, {
  "country": "Chad",
  "visits": 711
}, {
  "country": "Nicaragua",
  "visits": 665
}, {
  "country": "Albania",
  "visits": 580
}, {
  "country": "South Sudan",
  "visits": 443
}, {
  "country": "Cambodia",
  "visits": 441
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 395
}];

}
```

The error occurs when I try to reference `chart` at the start of the `updateChart()` function - specifically the code fragment `chart.data = [{...`.

This is my first posting, so I apologize if anything is missing - thank you all in advance!

Comment: What is the line 123 in the code you shared?

Comment: Apologies - that would be the first line of the function `updateChart()`, `chart.data = ...`

Comment: Try add in the `updateChart` function the lines for create again the chart instance: `chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);`.

Comment: No luck - instead of the earlier error, I now receive the warning `Chart was not disposed id-22` (details [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/chart-was-not-disposed/)), and the chart does not update. I assume this is because your suggestion attempts to draw an entirely new chart instead of updating the existing instance.